# Infinite dimensional vector space eigenvectors eigenvalues and representation

Tags: hilbert-spaces, transformation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We can express linear transformations with their eigenvectors and eigenvalues in finite vector spaces if they are diagonalizable. even if they are not diagonalizable we can express them via Jordan normal form. So my question is basically if it's also valid in infinite function spaces? Can I express, for example, the operator $d/dx$ via its eigenfunction $f(x) = exp(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean diagonalizable instead of invertible?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Yes you are tight of course. sorry

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane i editted it